# expandable textbox to fixed width

Tags: jquery, html

I am making an expandable textarea.

I am using [this tutorial.](http://www.9zap.com/jquery/expand-a-text-box-on-focus-using-jquery)

But i have a problem. These textfields (in the tutorial) are fixed in width. In my webpage i have a textfield that is 100px width and one that is 500px width. Is there i way i can make the script so i expands from en back to the widht i set in my webpage?

I just need Yes/No and a coding hint. I want to do the coding myself.

Comment: Yes, I would set `data-width` on both textfields like this `<textarea data-width="300px"/>`. And replace the fixed widths with `$(this).data("width")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can. You should get the CSS values of your text fields first and put them in some variables.
for example:

```
var mydivWidth = $('.mydiv').css("width");
```

then write the `animate` function as you want, using for example `hover` event handler, and for mouseout, use the variables.

again for example:

```
$('...').hover(function(){
    //your codes here
},function(){
    $('...').animate({width:mydivWidth});
});
```

I tried not to write all the codes :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you should look at selecting the specific element you are clicking on and determine it's width. There is jQuery functionality for all of that.

I could of course provide the code, but it sounds like you don't want that.

So is that enough of a hint?

Good luck!